# A Geography-ish Riddle

Tags: riddle, english, geography

Here's another riddle of mine, albeit one that's not as hard:
The name of which national capital city sounds as if it's composed of two Greek letters?

Answer (score 10):

Yeah your other one stumped me, but I got this one! :-)

> Cairo/Chi-Rho (only works in english)

Comment: Once again, I have been ninja'd!